# Upgrading Mac from High Sierra to Catalina broke "import pycurl"

Tags: python, ssl

I upgraded my Mac from High Sierra to Catalina but that broke `import pycurl`. See error below.

I  tried all the options that users claimed to have been successful with in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096436/ssl-backend-error-when-using-openssl/58405595#58405595) but of no avail.

```
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backend (none/other) is different from compile-time ssl backend (openssl)
```

My pycurl version is **7.43.0.3**

Python version is **3.6.4**.

*[I also tried it with Catalina's 1.0.2t and then tried `libressl` below]*

```
% openssl version -a
LibreSSL 2.8.3
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"

% echo $PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY 
openssl

% echo $LDFLAGS 
-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

% echo $CPPFLAGS 
-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

I tried all combos of commands above:

```
% pip install --global-option="--with-openssl" --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include --compile --no-cache-dir" pycurl

% brew uninstall openssl
```

etc.

I used easy_install.

**But it is just broken in *Catalina*!!** Did anyone resolve this yet?

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me though it seems a bit hacky.. maybe go with this until a better solution comes along?

```
brew install curl-openssl
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
export PYCURL_CURL_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin/curl-config
export LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/c-ares/lib -L/usr/local/opt/nghttp2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libmetalink/lib -L/usr/local/opt/rtmpdump/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libssh2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openldap/lib -L/usr/local/opt/brotli/lib'
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir
```

macOS 10.15
Python 3.7.4
pycurl 7.43.0.3
OpenSSL 1.0.2t

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
pip uninstall pycurl
pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running MacOS ventura on my MacBook Pro.
We use Ptyhon 3.7. The following worked for me:

```
% python3.7 -m pip uninstall pycurl
% brew install curl
% brew install openssl

% export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib $LDFLAGS"
% export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include $CPPFLAGS"
% export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig

% python3.7 -m pip install pycurl==7.45.2 --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/"
```